# Bringing items in a template instantiation scope unqualified into local scope

Tags: module, namespaces, scope, d

I want to bring *unqualified names* of functions in a template into my working/local scope. Eg.:

```
struct St {
    int t = 44;
}

template Inter(T) { // the 'base' template/interface/parameterized-module
    alias Self = T;

    void myfunc(ref self) {
        writeln("Inter: ", Self.stringof, " : ", 11);
    }
}

template Inter(T: St) {
      /+ ^^^^^ the 'specialization' which is really
         the implementation for the template-module for type `St`
      +/
    alias Self = T;

    void myfunc(ref Self self) {
        writeln("Inter TWO (St)! : ", Self.stringof, " : ", self.t);
    }
}

void main(string[] args){
    St s;

    /+  SOMETHING HERE  +/

    /+  s.myfunc(s);  +/ // <- I want to be able to do this
}
```

Something like a `mixin template` would work but at the cost of lots of needless code duplication (*I* wouldn't be duplicating anything but the compiler *would* have to work with lots of the same code).

Put another way: Yes, UFCS would probably not even work in this case even if I could bring `myfunc(self)` into scope of `main()`. But my question is *how do I bring stuff inside a template's scope openly/unqualified into another scope?* Or yet another way: Imagine I'm making a nested `module` (I don't know how to do this) that's inside a `mixin template`, instantiating the mixin with the type I want, then `import`ing everything in `mymodule_templ!MyType` into my working scope.

Ask for clarifications in the comments please. My questions are seldom readable on my first formulation of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `mixin template` so maybe you tried it and it didn't work.... but what you're asking for is exactly what a mixin template does:

```
import std.stdio;

struct St {
    int t = 44;
}

// it needs to be declared as a mixin template
mixin template Inter(T) {
    alias Self = T;

    void myfunc(ref self) {
        writeln("Inter: ", Self.stringof, " : ", 11);
    }
}

// the overload is also a mixin template....
mixin template Inter(T: St) {
    alias Self = T;

    void myfunc(ref Self self) {
        writeln("Inter TWO (St)! : ", Self.stringof, " : ", self.t);
    }
}


mixin Inter!St; // and this is where you mix it in to the current scope

void main(string[] args){
    St s;

    s.myfunc(); // boom, this works!
}
```

You could also mix it in to `main`, but UFCS won't work there simply because ufcs doesn't consider local symbols, it wouldn't work if you hand-wrote the function either. It only looks at the module level.

So the `mixin` keyword is the `import` functionality you're looking for.... unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: That still precludes the reuse of the same `mixin`ed template in other modules by simply importing, somehow. But yeah, you fixed the `mixin template` example I didn't even post, lol.

Comment: You can just import the module that mixes it in and everything will be visible normally.